# Launch script after Windows service start

Tags: windows, service, triggers

I would like to launch script after windows service start or restart.
Like monitor wsupdate and at start or restart execute a batch script test.bat

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

That could be easily done with a scheduled task:

You just need to:

**1)** Start and Stop the Service to got the appropriate Events in the Eventlog.

**2)** taskschd.msc and create a new Costum Task. As Trigger you can select the Events created before with the start and/or stop action.

**3)** As Action call your cmd/bat, whatever you want.

**Hint:**
You also can export the Event in the XML Format, explained here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer.aspx
and then import the XML Snippet into the Scheduld Task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! In event log > Security , start and stop appear to be event 7036 !? Is it the id i should use ? Cause It does launch the script !

Comment: Hy, yes something around ID 7000 should be start/stop action. Double check your Scheduld Task. Also hit the Link above for additional Instructions. Does your Script run proberly?